# What is the equivalent of the Mexican distinction "Titulo de Ingeniero en Sistemas Computacionales" in the U.S. higher education system?

Tags: united-states, degree, titles, mexico

An individual has a degree from a technology institute in Mexico. His diploma says, "El Tecnologico Nacional de Mexico otorga a [name] el titulo de Ingeniero en Sistemas Computacionales." In English this would be, "The National Technological Institute of Mexico awards the title of Computer Systems Engineer on [name]." Is this equivalent to a Bachelor of Science in Computer Systems?

Note: [This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/80911/us-uk-titles-vs-latam-ones-venezuela) is related, but seems specific to Venezuela

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Engineer's degree has no direct equivalence in the US. It is a five year post-highschool degree, the same as a 5 year master's program in many US Computer Science or Engineering departments. It is therefore equivalent to the German Diplom-Ingenieur (or the post-Padua MS).

In the US, it might be considered to be the equivalent of a B.S., but it is really more. If you check the plan of studies, which is much more prescribed than in the US, you will see an impressive amount of courses, but relatively little electives. I personally would equate it with an M.S., but nobody asks me.

Titles in Latin America in general reflect the old French system.

Comment: From your description, this sounds equivalent to an MEng rather than an MS.